# Why was my profile icon removed?

Tags: support, profile-picture

I logged in today to find that my icon has been switched to one of the default patterns. Now I can just put it back, but the icon I have been using is a sprite from a video game so I wanted to make sure it wasn't removed for copyright issues or something similar. I've used it for years without issue, but if any website were to notice and remove it for that reason this would be the one.

Here is the icon in question:

[image: Image of a blonde pixelated warrior with a sword]

Comment: I've just looked at your profile on sites where I moderate and I can't see any evidence that you've used anything other than this identicon as your profile image.

Comment: You might want to get this account - http://stackoverflow.com/users/212374/fr33dan - merged into the one you are using here.

Comment: @Laurel, that's not the problem here.

Comment: @ChrisF I realized that after the edit and comment (both of which happened after my comment). To be fair, the OP's idenicon *did* change, as can be seen [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150926032823/https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265844/should-i-not-use-the-generic-tag-if-my-solution-is-limited-to-a-specific-version)

Comment: Sorry, I'm on mobile and not very fast with typing here. And I'm confused because that profile looks like what I expected and I remember asking that question but don't know how I have 2 accounts.

Comment: This got nothing to do with Stack Exchange. You have several emails, with different Gravatar for each.

Comment: It sounds like I need to merge those accounts, set the image the way I want it and not worry about it. Clearly I screwed something up though so even if there is some bug at play here we won't be able to track it down since I don't know what I did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The account you are thinking of - https://stackoverflow.com/users/212374/fr33dan - is an unregistered account that you'd only have access to while the cookies that identified you as the owner existed on your machine.

You must have logged in on another machine or supplied different credentials when you created this registered account.

Use the ["contact us"](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) form to make a request that the unregistered account is merged into this registered one.

Answer (score 2):

The usual reason for removing an avatar is because someone has flagged it as offensive. Could that have happened in this instance?

The other reason I have seen people revert to their basic gravatar is because of minor issues with Gravatar itself.